# How to use mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a site (sports.com, let's say) and I'd like to set up mod_rewrite so that a visitor to "football.sports.com/america" is shown content from "sports.com/stuff/place.php?id=america". I'd still like visitors to the naked "sports.com" to see "stuff/index.php".

Sorry, I'm a real newb with this. I've tried and failed several times, heres what I have so far...

```
IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} football\.sports\.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ stuff/place.php?id=$1 [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) stuff/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
RewriteRule ^america$ america/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^america/$ stuff/place.php?id=america [NC,L]
```

Redirects `football.sports.com/america[/]` to `football.sports.com/stuff/place.php?id=america`. This is a static rule: it won't work with france for example.

If you need a generic way you need :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ stuff/place.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

To get naked site to be redirected, add:

```
RewriteRule ^$ stuff/index.php [L]
```

Redirects football.sports.com/ to football.sports.com/stuff/index.php
Eventually you can add the query string of necessary.